# Scalatest figuring out if test passed or failed after the fact

Tags: scala, scalatest

Is there anyway to figure out if a test passed or failed after the test was ran?
I need to perform certain actions after the test is ran and the actions are different depending on if the test passed or failed. I was looking to scalatest and it seems the afterEach method of the BeforeAndAfterEach trait would work with the actions I need to perform after, but can't figure how to tell if the test failed or passed? I was looking into the Reporter trait which seems to have what i'm looking for but not sure on how to implement it.

Also if there is an easy way to find out the name of the method that was ran and if it failed or passed would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read for you convenient http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic